# What is the rough scheme to verify the outbox message proof?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

What is the rough scheme to verify the outbox message proof? (or please point me to the code)
Do I understand correctly that it is a merkle inclusion proof of a given message to a particular commitment?

I wonder if it's possible in theory to verify the output proof on-chain (by providing a chain of headers, commitment operation, and proof itself) before the commitment is cemented?

Question from Slack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is a merkle inclusion proof of a given message to a particular commitment

That's basically it. The rollup can produce outbox messages, written in its state. The protocol verifies a merkle proof on the cemented commitment state, of the outbox message's inclusion

Answer from Slack.

Comment: Question: Got it, thanks! I wonder if it's possible in theory to verify the output proof on-chain (by providing a chain of headers, commitment operation, and proof itself) before the commitment is cemented?

Comment: Answer: In the current state I'm not sure how that's possible, the outbox is in a commitment, if it's not cemented it can still be refuted. What happens if you execute the outbox message for a commitment that is later removed?

Comment: It's still ok as a soft commitment I think, depending on the "value at risk" you can process withdrawals, same way as you wait X confirmations in blockchains with probabilistic finality